# Regex exclude /live and any url with dot from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have links:

```
/yktqxw
/fzvenbr/ohwtbl.css <
/osfqimq/live
/live <
/srjtsuv/qmvqgkz
```

I need to exclude link start `/live` and has any dot like `/folder/style.css` `/image.png` `/js/script.js`

My regex is

```
/^\/(?!(live))(?![\.])(?:.*)/gm
```

But I have problem with exclude url witch dot

https://regex101.com/r/DDDQAq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second negative lookahead excludes links that start with a dot instead of those containing a dot.
This will match all links on their own - if you need proper multiline support, you might want to add "\r\n" to the list of excluded charactes in the square brackets: https://regex101.com/r/yC0pXR/1
If you only need to match single urls, you don't need that.

```
^\/(?!live)[^.]*$
```

Comment: Multiline is for example. This is always one line. But regex is working, thank you. I understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is the expression you are looking for. You can also check it out here
https://regex101.com/r/T5AfU9/1
take care!

```js
/^\/(?!live)(?!(?:.*(?:[.]))).*$/gmi
```